# Symfony: Form should not contain extra fields with two forms on one page

Tags: forms, symfony

I am new with Symfony 3 and I am trying to build a page where I have two forms for two different entities. One for adding a wish and one for adding a comment. 
When I submit one form, the second one gives the error "This form should not contain extra fields".

I tried $form->get('submit')->isClicked() but it did not work.

I also tried allow_extra_fields => true, then I received the error that it tries to insert a wish although I submitted a Comment. Moreoever I used form->isValid() to check if the form is valid before trying to do the query.

How is it possible that it tries to submit both forms ?

Here is my controller:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Shaker\JRQBundle\Entity\Wish;
use Shaker\JRQBundle\Entity\User;
use Shaker\JRQBundle\Entity\Wishcom;
use Shaker\JRQBundle\Entity\Wishsol;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
public function wishAction (Request $request, $id) {
        $wish=$this->getWish($id);
        $arraywishcom=$this->getWishComs($wish);
        $arraywishsol=$this->getWishSols($wish);

        $wishcom = new Wishcom(); 
        $wishsol = new Wishsol();

        $formcom=$this->buildFormCom($wishcom);
        $formsol=$this->buildFormSol($wishsol);

            // store a comment or a solution
             if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

                $formcom->handleRequest($request);

                if ($formcom->isValid()) {
                    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    $security = $this->container->get('security.token_storage');
                    $token=$security->getToken();
                    $user=$token->getUser();
                    $wishcom->setUser($user);
                    $wishcom->setWish($wish);
                    $em->persist($wishcom);
                    $em->flush();
                    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', "Commentaire bien enregistré.");
                }

             $formsol->handleRequest($request);

                if ($formsol->isValid()) {
                    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    $security = $this->container->get('security.token_storage');
                    $token=$security->getToken();
                    $user=$token->getUser();
                    $wishsol->setUser($user);
                    $wishsol->setWish($wish);
                    $em->persist($wishsol);
                    $em->flush();
                    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', "Solution bien enregistrée.");
                }

            }

        return $this->render('ShakerJRQBundle:Home:wish.html.twig', array(
            'wish' => $wish,
            'formcom' => $formcom->createView(),
            'formsol' => $formsol->createView(),
            'wishcom' => $arraywishcom,
            'wishsol' => $arraywishsol));
    }
private function buildFormCom (Wishcom $wishcom) {
      //build the form for discussing the topic
        $formbuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->CreateBuilder(FormType::class, $wishcom, array('allow_extra_fields' => true));
        $formbuilder
            ->add('Type', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices'  => array(
                'Argument' => 'Argument',
                'Contre-argument' => 'Contre-argument',
                'Commentaire' => 'Commentaire')))
            ->add('Comment', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('Commenter', SubmitType::class);

            $formcom=$formbuilder->getForm();
            return $formcom;
}

private function buildFormSol (Wishsol $wishsol) {
      //build the form for adding a solution        
        $formbuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->CreateBuilder(FormType::class, $wishsol, array('allow_extra_fields' => true));
        $formbuilder
            ->add('Solution', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('Proposer une solution', SubmitType::class);

        $formsol=$formbuilder->getForm();
        return $formsol;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the common-sense perspective, this should not have happened. However, if you look at your generated markup (before submit), you will probably see that your form is named `form` and your fields are named `form[Comment]`, `form[Type]` etc. Note that both forms' field will have a `form` prefix.

The naming collision is what makes `Symfony` think you are about to submit both forms. You have two ways to resolving this:

**1. Make your forms submit to a different URL and redirect to common one once you're done.**

This involves adding a `setAction` call to both of your form builders. In some cases, this may be exactly what you want, but if your common code (that one that goes after submitting) relies to much of stuff that went out in form, this is just pain. For example:

```
$formbuilder = $this->get('form.factory')
    ->createBuilder(FormType::class, $wishcom);

$formbuilder
    ->add('Type', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices'  => array(
            'Argument' => 'Argument',
            'Contre-argument' => 'Contre-argument',
            'Commentaire' => 'Commentaire')
        )
    )
    ->add('Comment', TextareaType::class)
    ->add('Commenter', SubmitType::class)
    ->setAction('/formcom-submit') // <-- THIS

$formcom=$formbuilder->getForm();
```

**2. Create a `named` form builder.**

This is IMO more natural way of handling a form naming collision. Each of the forms will have its own name and thus when you call `handleRequest` only one of the forms will be "processed". For example:

```
$formbuilder = $this->get('form.factory')
    ->createNamedBuilder('formcom', FormType::class, $wishcom);
```

and:

```
$formbuilder = $this->get('form.factory')
    ->createNameBuilder('formsol', FormType::class, $wishsol);
```

Another thing worth investigating is whether you should move both forms into separate classes. In that case, you will get name uniqueness out of box and your code will most certainly feel cleaner. In any case, if you about to reuse this form in a different action, I would say go for it.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you very much for a fast a helpful answer!  I use the createNamedBuilder method. As I am not using the forms outside this page I hadn't thought about making classess out of them. But thank you for the tip !

Comment: Glad I could help ;)

Comment: Thank You very much. I don't know why Symfonys' creators hide this method...
I just checked:
createBuilder -> 347k of results (64 on symfony.com)
createNamedBuilder -> less than 10k of results (6 on symfony.com)